# How to get each folder in the current directory and iterate it into a script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm making a backup script to zip up files and ftp them to a windows server. What I have now works, but it requires an argument for each folder I want to backup individually when I execute it. /path/ may contain many folders that I want to backup and I'd like to automate this script to get each folder in /path/ and back them up into their own .zip by running the script one time. Can anyone offer any insight into how to do this? Or at least how I can get each directory and iterate though?

```
#!/bin/sh
HOST='x.x.x.x'
USER='user'
PASSWD='pass'
now=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")
cd /path/
PROC=$1
DIR="$PROC"
FILE="$PROC"."$now.zip"
echo $FILE
zip -r $FILE $DIR
ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
binary
mkdir $PROC
cd $PROC
put $FILE
quit
END_SCRIPT
#exit 0
~
```

Comment: /path/ will contain folders such as /path/dir1, /path/dir2, /path/dir3, etc, I basically want to create a .zip file called dir1.zip, dir2.zip, dir3.zip, without going into those directories and making zips of any subdirectories that might exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
cd /path
for dir in */; do echo "$dir"; done
```

The trailing slash limits the wildcard results to be only directories in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started...

```
find /path -type d -depth 1 | while read DIR ; do
    BARE_DIR=$(basename $DIR)
    FILE="${BARE_DIR}.${now}.zip"
    zip -r $FILE $DIR
    ftp -n $HOST <<'    END_SCRIPT'
    quote USER $USER
    quote PASS $PASSWD
    binary
    mkdir $BARE_DIR
    cd $BARE_DIR
    put $FILE
    quit
    END_SCRIPT
done
```

Replace `/path` with your starting point.

*updated to restrict directory depth based upon comments*

Comment: find will list the directories recursively. This may or not be what the asker wants. The implementation of find may have a maxdepth option that you can use to control this, otherwise you can pipe ls into a loop and simply check if the file is a directory.

Comment: Very true, the question is vague.  I presumed it was a simple directory structure with only one dir each.

Comment: Right, I want to make a .zip of the contents of each directory in the working directory only and don't want to go into subdirectories.

Comment: The only thing I would add is use `-print0` and then use `read -r -d $'\0';` This will handle whitespaces in file names and other strange characters (like NL in file names).

Answer (score -2):

You can get a list of files in the /path/ directory with the glob pattern `/path/*` and iterate over them in a `for` loop:

```
for f in /path/*
do
    DIR="$f"
    FILE="$f.$now.zip"
    zip -r $FILE $DIR
    ...
done
```

Comment: This will break for all names containing spaces. You don't need `$(echo )`, simply use `for f in /path/*/`

Comment: you don't need quotes here ``DIR=$f`` but you need quotes here ``zip -r "$FILE" "$DIR"``